How can I type the label of the enumerate environment in beamer?
I write the following code
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}[title]
        Algorithm: 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item do this;
            \item if A, then return (1);
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

and I want to change "(1)" to the circled one as the label. How can I achieve this?


unrelated, but the block title needs to be in {...}, not [...]

You could mimic the enumerate item like this:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
    \usebeamercolor{item projected}
    {\pgftransformscale{1.75}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
    {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
      \pgftext{%
        \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
        \color{fg}#1}}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{title}
        Algorithm: 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item do this;
            \item if A, then return \foo{1};
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


